# Display multiple images with express

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, http, express

This might really be two question, however I am going to try to ask them together because they are tightly related. I am wondering if express (as in nodejs express) has a way to treat all requests the same. The same way http treats requests, for example:

```
pathname = url.parse(request.url).pathname;
```

Th reason that I want to do this is because I am working on a server that allows people to both upload and view images. I would like to be able to have another page that these images go to when clicked on. This page would display the image and have a voting system so that people could vote on the image. I think that the below way would be the best way to do this, however if there is a better way please let me know.
The way that I am thinking of doing it would be: 
1) someone clicks `image12.jpg` 
2) html redirects to *localhost:xxxx/image/image12* 
3) this opens `image.html` 
4) `image.html` looks at the path and displays *image12.jpg*.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your first question, I think studying think link will be helpful : https://expressjs.com/en/guide/routing.html

Basically you can do:

```
 req.all("/*",function(req,res){
 });
```

I think the way you are doing is okay, but you can also do this :
1) someone clicks image12.jpg 
2) directly opens image12.jpg.

** To achieve this you can call href="image/image12" and render the page with image12 from express.

You can do : Where id = image12

```
req.get("/image/:id", function(req,res){
})
```

Please let me know if this answers your question.

Comment: Thanks for you answer! sorry for my late reply :( I was wondering what you think the best way to implement a voting system? if I have the server point to the image directly then I cannot make it pretty or have a voting system. anyway thanks again!

Comment: @ZoeCarver When you get a request to the server for that image then you can know the user clicked on that image and add that count to your database if you are using a database ! If you let me know how you are storing the votes I can answer this better.

Comment: I have no current way of storing votes (i do not have a database either) I was wondering what people thought would be the best way

Comment: I got the kudos thing working :) thanks for your help. now i just need to work on css :(

Comment: @ZoeCarver I think you should store the votes somewhere(some sort of database). If you are storing in a array or variable in Node server, once you restart the server you will loose the data. Good luck with css !